# windows hard drive will not boot or mount - cyclic redundancy check - but mounts fine in osx

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot

I have a windows laptop that would not boot, so I have taken out my hard drive from my windows laptop and attached it to a sata cable and I can see the hard drive no problem from my mac/osx but when I try to read it from another windows machine (to run check disk) I cant seem to mount it, it gives me this error - cyclic redundancy check.

Is there anything I can do to repair this?

thanks
Joel

Comment: `it gives me this error` What error?

Comment: Thanks for the downvote, the error is in the title "cyclic redundancy check"

Comment: Hooked up to the other machine how? What program is giving the error? does Windows see the drive itself (even though it may not mount?).

Comment: Hi Gman, the drive was in the windows laptop, I removed it and connected it via a usb/sata cable kit, when I connect it to a mac, I can read it fine, but when I connect it to another windows machine it doesnt mount, doesnt show up in the drives etc.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up opening a command prompt in my good windows machine and ran:

```
chkdsk /f E:
```

This fixed the errors and I was able to put back in original machine and boot.